# if statement with equal sign "=" and not "==" in expression

Tags: c

I found a bug in code (the if statement should have had "==" instad of "=") and I have few questions.

Example code:

```
int i = 5;
if (i = MyFunction())  // MyFunction() returns an int; this is where bug was made
{
  // call A()
}
else
{
  // call B()
}
```

From what I gather it should always call A().
1. Is my assumption correct()?
2. Is this case for all/most compilers (any exceptions)?

Comment: if `MyFunction` returns 0, then `B()` is called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No, it will only call `A()` if the assignment is considered true, i.e. non-zero.
2. Yes, this is standard. It's not a very good way to write the code since the risk of confusion is large.

Some people flip comparisons, writing the constant to the left, to avoid the risk:

```
if( 12 == x )
```

but of course this wouldn't have worked in your case, since it really is an assignment. Most compilers can give you a warning when this code is detected, since it's so often a cause of bugs.

Comment: Those flipped conditions are referred to as „Yoda conditions“ („If 12 is the count, do this and that“). See http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html

Comment: Also, the yoda nonsense has been obsolete since 1990 when Borland released a compiler that yielded warnings for "possibly incorrect assignment". Every half-decent compiler since then has that warning. So don't obfuscate your code, make sure you get a compiler warning instead.

Comment: @Lundin - yes absolutely, glad to see some common sense here.  I've never made this mistake in my career, I've only ever seen it made once in my career, there are things like compilers, static analysis, code reviews and testing to catch this, and ultimately the readability is compromised by letting Yoda get behind the keyboard.  I've even seen this ham-fisted technique *spread like a virus* so that coders (who obviously don't understand the **original** intent of the form) to write things like 'if ( 4 < foo)'.  Ouch.

Answer (score 6):

If `MyFunction()` returns zero (`0`) it will call B(); otherwise it will call A().  The value of an assignment expression is the value that is assigned to the left hand side; in an `if` statement 0 is treated as false and all other values as true.

This is perfectly legitimate code, although many compilers will issue a warning.  The reason it is valid is that in C and similar languages, assignment is an expression (rather than a statement).

If you intended to assign to `i` and test the return value you should write `if ((i = MyFunction()))`; the extra parentheses signal to the compiler (and to the reader) that the assignment is intended.

If instead you intend to test against the value of `i` you should write `if (MyFunction() == i)`; by putting the function call on the left you ensure that if you miss out the double equals sign the code will fail to compile (`MyFunction() = i` is not usually a valid expression).

Answer (score 4):

This statement is an assignment:

```
i = MyFunction()
```

The if statement is in effect checking the value of i. If MyFunction() returns 0, i is assigned 0 and it becomes equivalent to:

```
if(0)
```

This evaluates to false, and A() will not be called in this case

Answer (score 3):

It will take the true branch (i.e. call `A`) if the function return is non-zero. Zero is treated as false so if `MyFunction()` returns zero it will call `B` instead.

In practice, yes this is correct for most / all compilers. I think 0=false was just a convention; I wouldn't be surprised if it is now formalised in C99 or later but I don't have a copy handy to refer you to the right section.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is incorrect.

The expression in the `if`-condition is evaluated like any other expression, in your case the result of `(i = MyFunction())` is the return value of `MyFunction()`.

Answer (score 2):

You code will evaluate

```
  (i = MyFunction())
```

and if `MyFunction()` returns a non zero value, the expression will be evaluated as true and call `A()`. Otherwise `B()`